# how to use django Serializer or signal to add object in database?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I create ticket , ticketflow , ticketstate , tickettype models

i need a serializer or signal that when user create ticket programmatically add ticketflow object and set state of ticket to submited or something else

Here is my models

```
class TicketType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title    


class TicketState(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title    

class Ticket(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4 , editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    ticket_type = models.ForeignKey(TicketType,on_delete=models.CASCADE , default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    message = models.TextField()    
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/tickets/', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf','docx','zip','jpg','png'])], blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title  

class TicketFlow(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket,on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='ticketflow')
    ticket_state = models.ForeignKey(TicketState,on_delete=models.CASCADE , default=1 , related_name='ticketstate')
    message = models.TextField()    
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/tickets/', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf','docx','zip','jpg','png'])], blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']
```

here is my serializers

```
class TicketTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TicketType
        fields = ('id','title',)

class TicketStateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TicketState
        fields = ('id','title',)

class TicketSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ['id' , 'author', 'ticket_type','title' ,'message' , 'attachment'  , 'created_on']


class TicketFlowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TicketFlow
        fields = ['author', 'ticket_state', 'message', 'attachment', 'created_on', 'updated_on']
```

It'll be great if someone can help me out in this. how can i create signal or override create method in serializers

Answer (score 0):

You probably want your "state" field to be read-only in the serializer, this way it can only be changed programmatically, and in the model set a default value with `default='pending'`. 
Then you can override the `update` method in a Serializer (see the doc [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)):

```py
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        validated_data['state'] = 'edited'
        return super(MySerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: how about state is Foreign Key field ?

Comment: Well I can't really guess it, right ? :) Add your models etc so we can help you more

Comment: i added model and serializers and change questions . can you help me