# best way to edit or update object in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

i'm new in django and django rest framework,

i create an app with multiple models and they have ForeignKey and ManytoManyField

My question is what is the best way to add object, update field , set value (ForeignKey),or create object in django when have multiple models with multiple relations
Signals , override save , create , update method in serializers or anything else

Comment: Please clarify... You can include snippets what you have done so members can have better understanding of what you want.

Comment: please see this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71293002/how-to-use-django-serializer-or-signal-to-add-object-in-database)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/HackSoftware/Django-Styleguide) would help